# Angular universal(ssr rendering) with ngx-restangular not working properly

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, ngx-restangular

I have a project, which was implemented with **ngx-restangular**. I am using Angular universal for ssr rendering, after this `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr` it doesn't generate pages correctly, sometimes it is working correctly sometimes not. Here is the result after ssr rendering with ngx-restangular:

[image]

And when I am replacing **ngx-restangular** with usual **HttpClient** everything is working fine, after
this experiment I understand that the problem is connected with **ngx-restangular**.

My question is following how I can fix this issue, can I without removing  this **ngx-restangular**  module fix this issue?

Comment: Any error server side?

Comment: No, I don't have any error in console, and  also in terminlal console.